# Oauth 2 flow : Should AWS Cognito's id_token be passed to the browser for session management?

Tags: security, spring-security, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I am creating an application where :

1. I have a REST API - /hello
2. The user should be able to access this API only if he/she is logged in.

For this purpose, I decided to use AWS Cognito and implement the Oauth 2.0 flow.

Now, when the user tries to access /hello, they get redirected to an AWS Cognito login page. After the user logs in, my server side application (containing the REST API /hello) can get the id_token and access_token from AWS Cognito.

Should I pass this id_token to the browser, and ask the browser to send it while accessing the /hello REST API? Does this have any security implications? Is this the right way?

Or, after the user is authenticated, should I create a new id_token which is signed by my own custom key, and then send it to the browser? The user will send it back while trying to access the /hello REST API. I will then validate whether the id_token is valid using my custom key.

The purpose of the id_token is to validate that the user's session is valid and has not expired. Should the id_token be used for session management?

Answer (score 0):

So the goal is to avoid use of cookies in your React Web UI, and to use tokens instead, with a stateless back end. I totally agree with this goal.

**OPTION 1**

Pass tokens from the web back end to the UI which can use them to maintain a client side session. This requires a Spring endpoint that is called via Ajax and it needs to be secured via cookies. Otherwise an attacker can call that endpoint and get tokens.

**OPTION 2**

Do the OAuth login handling in your React app via the [oidc client library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) rather than in a Spring web back end, so that your UI is a pure cookieless SPA. Use Spring solely as an OAuth secured resource server. Use static content hosting for HTML / JS files, perhaps via AWS Cloudfront.

**MY SOLUTIONS**

If interested in option 2 I have a demo React app that works like this and connects to Cognito. You can run it yourself from my [Quick Start Page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/).

Here is the [SPA OAuth Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts). Meanwhile my [Spring Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot) only acts as a Rest API and does not do any web login handling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not answer my question : "Should I pass this id_token to the browser?". I know that the access token is used by the Client application to access resources on the Resource server.

Comment: Usually the id token is passed directly to the browser (for an SPA) - or handled server side if using a web app that runs security code on the server side. Either way the code is usually done for you by a library. If you let me know the tech stack you are using I can provide a more tailored answer.

Comment: Out of interest, is there something AWS specific that suggests sending the id token to the resource server? It is not standard to do so but sometimes vendors require this type of thing, which can add complexity to your app. I try to only use standards based behaviour.

Comment: I'm using Spring security on the backend with React on the frontend as the tech stack. Thus, once the user is authenticated on AWS Cognito, I need something to maintain a session. By default, Spring uses the JSESSION_ID cookie for this. The point is if we want to have stateless sessions, then we could send the id_token sent by AWS Cognito to the browser.

Comment: Again, the question is not about sending the id_token to the resource server. In the Oauth 2.0 or OIDC flow, the access token is sent to the resource server. 
The question is Should I pass the id_token generated by AWS Cognito to the browser? The answer that I can derive from your comment is "Yes, you can".

Comment: Cool - I understand your goal now, to build a cookieless SPA. I've updated my answer and I think you'll need to either accept cookies or move to a client side flow. This is quite tricky and there is a lot of stuff about this on my blog if it helps.